# Retrofit2 doesn't include the Authorization Token

Tags: android, curl, retrofit2

I'm trying to do an @GET request with Retrofit2. I'm just have a good request to take the token making a login, but now when I'm trying to do this call I don't get anything.

This is the error shows by an interceptor:

```
╭--- cURL (http://192.168.1.107/project-task)
curl -X GET -H "Host: 192.168.1.107" -H "Connection: Keep-Alive" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -H "User-Agent: okhttp/3.4.1" --compressed http://192.168.1.107/project-task
╰--- (copy and paste the above line to a terminal)
--> GET http://192.168.1.107/project-task http/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.107
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: okhttp/3.4.1
--> END GET
<-- 401 Unauthorized http://192.168.1.107/project-task (167ms)
X-Powered-By: Sails <sailsjs.org>
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="Users"
set-cookie: sails.sid=s%3Aw3NbP_fcx-rnmnDaJSIUcs_ZgQB5ar5B.dZogKwU4nOlmmplnjqMZAUbL4eshjLITmBpkiZLdNkU; Path=/; HttpOnly
Date: Mon, 05 Sep 2016 11:25:09 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<-- END HTTP
```

The call that I make with the GET is:

```
@GET("project-task")
Call<RootContainer> getChargeAccountsNTasks(@Header("Authorization") String token);
```

The implementation used with this is the next code, but crashs con the call object, and I think that it is because the token is not added to the header.

```
public class DataApiRequestImpl implements DataApiRequest {

    private GetDataRequestEntity getDataRequestEntity;

    private RetrofitApi retrofitApi;

    @Inject
    public DataApiRequestImpl(
            GetDataRequestEntity getDataRequestEntity,
            RetrofitApi retrofitApi) {
        this.getDataRequestEntity = getDataRequestEntity;
        this.retrofitApi = retrofitApi;
    }

    @Override
    public RootContainer getChargeAccountsNTasks(String token) throws Exception {
        RootContainer data = null;
        Call<RootContainer> call = retrofitApi.getChargeAccountsNTasks(token);
        Response<RootContainer> response = call.execute();
        data = response.body();
        return data;
    }

}
```

How I can know if the token is being added to the header?

EDIT: 
Added UserModule, which has the initialization methods to do calls.

```
@Module
public class UserModule {

    public UserModule() {}

    @Provides
    public Retrofit retrofit() {
        OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            CurlLoggingInterceptor curlLoggingInterceptor = new CurlLoggingInterceptor();
            okHttpClientBuilder.addNetworkInterceptor(curlLoggingInterceptor);

            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS);
            okHttpClientBuilder.addNetworkInterceptor(interceptor);
        }

        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClientBuilder.build())
                .build();
    }

    @Provides
    public RetrofitApi userRetrofitApi(Retrofit retrofit) {
        return retrofit.create(RetrofitApi.class);
    }

    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    LoginUser provideLoginUserInteractor(LoginUserInteractor interactor) {
        return interactor;
    }

    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    LogoutUser provideLogoutUserInteractor(LogoutUserInteractor interactor) {
        return interactor;
    }

    @Provides
    public LoginRequestEntity loginRequestEntity() {
        return new LoginRequestEntity();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing Authorization as a parameter not Header. I will show you the example code which I've done before using OkHttp:

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = getOkHttpClient();


httpClient.interceptors().clear();
httpClient.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request original = chain.request();

        // Set authorization token here
        Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", token)
                .header("Connection", "close")
                .method(original.method(), original.body());

        Request request = requestBuilder.build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
});



Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .client(httpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build();
// Assign retorfitAPI like this
RetrofitApi retrofitApi = retrofit.create(serviceClass);
```

And then call the API.

Comment: I'm using MVP architecture and Dagger 2, so I can't do it like this, I think. I create the retrofit class and the authorization token will be injected later, so, I don't know how to do it. I have added more source code to the question. Thanks